# Relation between sampling size and estimation error

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, estimation, sampling

Let $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$ be two real random variables, normally distributed as above.

Let also $Q$ be the following non-negative quantity:
$$
Q = \left\lvert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right\rvert,
$$
where $x_i$'s, $y_i$'s are drawn from the distributions $\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, respectively.

If $n\to\infty$, then $Q\to\lvert\mu_y-\mu_x\rvert$. Is there any error bound for the above estimation? To put it better: can we have a rule about the sampling size $n$, so that the above estimation of that distance between the sample means are of some given accuracy $\epsilon$?

More interestingly, if $\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \Sigma_x)$ and $\mathbf{y}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \Sigma_y)$ are multi-variate ($d$-dimensional) normal vectors, of given means and covariance matrices, and $\mathbf{x}_i$, $\mathbf{y}_i$ are drawn from them, respectively, what would be the error for the estimation of the norm $\lVert\mu_y-\mu_x\rVert$ by the quantity
$$
\left\lVert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{y}_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_i\right\rVert
$$

Again, what I'm looking for, is a relation between the sample size $n$ and the dimensionality $d$, so that the estimation is of some accuracy (say $\epsilon$).

It seems reasonable to me that, if the dimensionality of the variables $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are getting high, then the sample size $n$ needed to achieve a "good" (of given error) estimation of the above quantity, would get high, too. The question is how much high? I guess it wouldn't be just a polynomial relation, but maybe exponential. But this is only a guess.

The above might be trivial for statisticians, but I'm not sure even about where to look for. Could you help me with some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comments:**

You could start by using Chebyshev's Inequality to get a bound on $|\bar X_n - \mu_x|$ that shows $\bar X_n \stackrel{prob}{\rightarrow} \mu_x.$ Similarly for the $Y_i,$ and so on.

However, in practice, it might be more useful to find the normal
distribution of $\bar Y_n - \bar X_n$, and observe that its variance
decreases to $0$ with increasing $n.$ For specified numerical values
of the parameters, you could get the *exact* distribution of $Q,$ based on this normal distribution. (The Chebyshev bounds are good enough
to show convergence in probability, but generally too loose to be useful
in practice. Chebyshev's Inequality works for *all* distributions with 
a finite variance, so the bounds tend not to be very tight for *any one* distribution.)

If you look at the development of 'Hotelling's $T^2$ distribution' you might
find approaches useful for the multivariate version of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question! So, it seems that there is no general method for working on such stuff. Actually, I used this simple quantity (Q) just because it makes the problem quite clear (I think). In fact, I'm interested in quantities of the form $\max(0,\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{x}+b)+\max(0,\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{y})$, which I would like to estimate using $n$ "observations" of each random vector ($\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$), by taking the means. Do you think I should try to find how this quantity is distributed?

Comment: Too often users on this site think it appropriate to suggest our [companion site](http://stats.stackexchange.com) for any but the most trivial or mathematical of statistics questions. But _your question_ has the kind of 'big-data' and 'multivariate' flavor that makes me think you might get a more comprehensive answer there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your comments anyway! I'll do as you suggest (I like CVSE, it's a good community, but often less responsive than MathSE). I'll also try your suggestions above; actually I would like to have a (toy) example, where I could show that when the dimensionality $d$ increases, one would need (maybe exponentially?) more samples (maybe $n=a\exp(bd)$?) to have a good estimation (well, $\exp$ is just a guess). Thanks again for your help; it's much appreciated :)